# ArcGIS Server 10 installation possible in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: arcgis-server, ubuntu

I have a machine with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and want to install ArcGIS Server 10 in it. I find that the supported OS are RHEL and SUSE Linux in ESRI website and I also find in some postings that it is not possible in Ubuntu. Does anyone have any idea about it?